# Controls are not displayed on Microsft Edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I have special checkbox they are not displayed (Visible) on Microsoft Edge, everything is working on IE and Chrome and Safari

I am using :

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

If I delete the :  -webkit-appearance: none; the checkbox appear but I will lose my new style on other browser

How can I fix this on Edge ?

Comment: IE is not a webkit browser. Neither is Chrome but it recognizes those vendor prefixes. I don't know what an equivalent property for Edge is. However, you shouldn't use properties with vendor prefixes which can disappear tomorrow and can be inconsistent, can change, and unreliable and are non-standard anyway (in many cases).

Comment: thanks Rob, my main idea is not hide the default checkbox and build my own with css, in the case I don't have to use the prefixes to hide the default checkbox what can I use else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edge isn't a webkit browser, nor is Firefox (hence the -moz prefix). 
Use the full declaration for complete browser coverage:

```
.yourclass{
   -webkit-appearance: value;
   -moz-appearance:    value;
   appearance:         value;
}
```

See here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/

For a full breakdown of browsers that do/dont support this, have a look at [CanIuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=appearance)

Comment: I already try -moz-appearance:    none; but style not seeing the checkbox